# android how to get the sensor step counter data only one day?

Tags: android, sensors

I want to get the app user's steps data, but I got the data wasn't current day's, how can I to get the only current day data?

```
 public StepCounterRecord(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)reactContext.getSystemService(reactContext.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mReactContext = reactContext;
    }

    public int start(int delay) {
    this.delay = delay;
    if ((mStepCounter = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)) != null) {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        return (1);
    }
    return (0);
}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;
    WritableMap map = mArguments.createMap();

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        i++;
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > delay) {
            i = 0;
            map.putDouble("steps", sensorEvent.values[0]);
            sendEvent("StepCounter", map);
            lastUpdate = curTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 3):

The [Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) returns the number of steps taken by the user since the last reboot while activated.
Therefore, if you want to get the steps of today, you should calculate programmatically.
Below code is my idea for calcualte it

```
private int milestoneStep;

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    int totalStepSinceReboot = sensorEvent.values[0];

    int todayStep = getPreferences(today());
    if(todayStep == 0){
        milestoneStep = totalStepSinceReboot;
    }else{
        int additionStep = totalStepSinceReboot - milestoneStep;
        savePreferences(today(), todayStep + additionStep);
        milestoneStep = totalStepSinceReboot;

        Log.i("TAG","Your today step now is "+getPreferences(today()));
    }
}


private void savePreferences(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void getPreferences(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    return; = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);

}

public String today() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account if the app not opened for more than one day.

Comment: @AhmedKorany yes, of course. to count step event you don't open app, you can try using Service (but user still able to kill Service) or you can use GoogleFit for get step

Comment: @Linh Thanks for the information you provided. Does this code still work properly? and can you review my code too?