# Android Studio Java, Accessing Step Counter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-fit

I'm kind of confused on how the Step Counter in Android works. I got my code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662085/8685682) but it always seems to return `0`.

Here's how my code looks:

```
// I removed stuff that was specific to Ionic Capacitor, which I am using. 
public class Steps extends Plugin {

    public void echo(PluginCall call) {
        Log.i("TAG","Your today step now is "+getPreferences(today()));
    }

    private int getPreferences(String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);
    }

    public String today() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }

}
```

I've looked at the docs, but I'm unsure if this is even the data that I need.

1. What's the difference between what I'm doing here and getting step count from Google Fit?
2. Is there a global step counter for my Android device or is that limited to Google Fit?
3. If it does exist, can I and how do I access it without going through the Google Fit auth?

EDIT: I've also noticed that my app isn't requesting Physical Activity permissions despite adding:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

To my Manifest. However even after enabling it manually from the settings I still only get `0` when fetching steps.

Comment: Why are you expecting step counts to be present in `SharedPreferences`? I don't see anything in your code that relates to step counts.

Comment: @GraemeMorgan I supposed that would be where that data was saved, but you're right. So what's the solution?